Astro cargar archivo de otro puerto para transmision hls
En mi aplicacion astro(puerto 4321) quiero mostrar un streaming hls generado desde otra servidor(puerto 3000)
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
    <script is:inline>
        document.addEventListener('astro:page-load', () => {
            if (Hls.isSupported()) {
                const video = document.getElementById('video');
                const hls = new Hls();
                hls.attachMedia(video);
                hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
                    hls.loadSource("http://localhost:3000/192.168.0.64/output.m3u8");
                    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
                        console.log("manifest loaded, found " + data.levels.length + " quality level");
                    });
                });
            }
        }, { once: true });
    </script>

En el localhost 3000 ya tengo esta carpeta con los archivos output.m3u8, output85.ts, output86.ts, output87.ts
No se si esta correcto mi codigo para poder acceder a ese archivo
